# How to use equational reasoning to reduce this expression

Tags: haskell

I have the following definitions:

```hs
fibs = 1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs

scanl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> [a] 
scanl f q ls =
    q : (case ls of 
            [] ->[]
            x:xs -> scanl f (f q x) xs
        )

take                   :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
take n _      | n <= 0 =  []
take _ []              =  []
take n (x:xs)          =  x : take (n-1) xs
```

I would like to reduce the following expression:

```
take 3 (fibs)
```

So, I would proceed:

```
take 3 (fibs)
= 
take 3 (1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs)
= 
1 : take 2 (scanl (+) 1 fibs)
= 
1 : take 2 (scanl (+) 1 (1 : (scanl (+) 1 fibs)))
=
...
```

How can I continue reasoning ?

EDIT: I continued my reasoning but the last line is incorrect, because the next computed Fibonacci number should be 5. How can I solve this problem ?

```
take 3 (fibs)
= 
take 3 (1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs)
= 
1 : take 2 (scanl (+) 1 fibs)
= 
1 : take 2 (scanl (+) 1 (1 : (scanl (+) 1 fibs)))
= 
1 : take 2 (1 : scanl (+) 2 (scanl (+) 1 fibs))
= 
1 : 1 : take 1 (scanl (+) 2 (scanl (+) 1 fibs))
= 
1 : 1 : take 1 (scanl (+) 2 (1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs))
= 
1 : 1 : take 1 (2 : scanl (+) 3 (scanl (+) 1 fibs))
= 
1 : 1 : 2 : take 0 (scanl (+) 3 (1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs))
= 
1 : 1 : 2 : take 0 (3 : scanl (+) 4 (1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs))
= 
...
```

Comment: Apply `scanl (+) a (b:bs) = a : scanl (+) (a+b) bs` which follows by your definition of `scanl`.

Comment: Thank you, @chi ! That helped, though you can see the second argument to `scanl` in my last line is incorrect. Should be 5. Could you give some insight ? I am surely doing something wrong. Will post soon.

Comment: In the middle (~6th step) you rewrote `(scanl (+) 1 fibs)` as `(1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs)` but that's wrong. Should have been `(scanl (+) 1 (1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs))`. The answer below explains it, anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With equational reasoning, you can typically expand terms in any order you want, and it will *usually* result in the same result.  You've found the exception -- if you pick a particularly bad order of expansion, like continually expanding the `fibs` term while ignoring the `scanl` term, your solution may appear to loop indefinitely without producing any results, whereas Haskell has no problem evaluating it.

If you want to expand your program the same way Haskell actually evaluates it, you need to understand that terms are evaluated when and only when the evaluation is required for pattern matching, either in an explicit `case` statement or in the implicit case statement of a function definition with patterns.

So, when Haskell evaluates `take 3 fibs` the *reason* it needs to evaluate/expand the `fibs` term is because the pattern matches in the definition of `take` require pattern matching on the second argument whenever the first argument is positive.  In detail, Haskell first tries to match the pattern:

```
take n _ | n <= 0 = ...
```

This requires evaluation of `n`, which is already evaluated as `3`.  Because the guard fails, Haskell next tries to match the pattern:

```
take _ [] = ...
```

and this requires evaluating the second argument because that's the only way Haskell can tell if it is or isn't an empty list.

In your (pre-edit) expansion, you actually followed this rule -- even if you didn't realize you were following it -- up to this term.

```
1 : take 2 (scanl (+) 1 fibs)
```

When Haskell tries to evaluate the `take` here, because `2` is positive, it needs to evaluate the second argument.  But evaluation of the second argument doesn't immediately start by expanding `fibs`.  That's only going to happen if `scanl` pattern matches on its third argument, so we need to see what `scanl` is doing first.  From the code, the definition:

```
scanl f q ls = ...
```

can be applied with no pattern matching at all, so the correct expansion (meaning the expansion that matches how Haskell would actually try to evaluate it) is:

```
1 : take 2 (scanl (+) 1 fibs)
=
1 : take 2 (1 : (case fibs of { [] -> []; x:xs -> scanl (+) ((+) 1 x) xs }))
```

Now, `take` has enough information about its second argument to continue so the expansion would continue by applying the definition of `take`:

```
1 : 1 : take 1 (case fibs of { [] -> []; x:xs -> scanl (+) ((+) 1 x) xs })
```

This next `take` also needs to expand its second argument to make progress.  The `case` statement needs to expand `fibs` to pattern match, so the next part of the expansion should be:

```
1 : 1 : take 1 (case (1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs) of { [] -> []; x:xs -> scanl (+) ((+) 1 x) xs })
```

which is enough information for the `case` to proceed (by applying the second case with `x=1` and `xs=scanl (+) 1 fibs`):

```
1 : 1 : take 1 (scanl (+) ((+) 1 1) (scanl (+) 1 fibs))
```

For `take` to progress, it needs to inspect its second argument, which is a `scanl`.  This `scanl` can proceed without further evaluation by direct application of the definition:

```
1 : 1 : take 1 (((+) 1 1) : case scanl (+) 1 fibs of { [] -> []; x:xs -> scanl (+) ((+) ((+) 1 1) x) xs })
```

Now, `take` as enough information to proceed:

```
1 : 1 : ((+) 1 1) : take 0 (case scanl (+) 1 fibs of { [] -> []; x:xs -> scanl (+) ((+) ((+) 1 1) x) xs })
```

At this point, assuming all list elements have been demanded in order, Haskell's next order of business will be to evaluate the third element:

```
1 : 1 : 2 : take 0 (case scanl (+) 1 fibs of { [] -> []; x:xs -> scanl (+) ((+) ((+) 1 1) x) xs })
```

and the last order of business is to evaluate `take` which requires no further evaluation of its second argument when its first argument is zero, so we just get:

```
1 : 1 : 2 : []
```

which is the final answer.

As I say, this is how Haskell would actually evaluate your program.  (Well, it might do it a little differently because of optimizations, but the answer is guaranteed to be the same.)

Your alternate order in the edit will also work, though you're doing more evaluation than Haskell will.  The reason you're getting the wrong answer is that this step:

```
1 : 1 : take 1 (scanl (+) 2 (scanl (+) 1 fibs))
=
1 : 1 : take 1 (scanl (+) 2 (1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs))
```

is incorrect.  If you want to expand that second `scanl` following your approach, you'll need to expand `fibs` again first:

```
1 : 1 : take 1 (scanl (+) 2 (scanl (+) 1 fibs))
=
1 : 1 : take 1 (scanl (+) 2 (scanl (+) 1 (1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs)))
```

and now you can apply the definition of `scanl` to the second occurrence:

```
1 : 1 : take 1 (scanl (+) 2 (1 : scanl (+) (1 + 1) (scanl (+) 1 fibs)))
```

and to the first occurrence:

```
1 : 1 : take 1 (2 : scanl (+) (2 + 1) (scanl (+) (1 + 1) (scanl (+) 1 fibs))
=
1 : 1 : 2 : take 0 (scanl (+) (2 + 1) (scanl (+) (1 + 1) (scanl (+) 1 fibs))
```

No more evaluation is necessary but if you really want to go further, you'll have to expand `fibs` *again* before expanding the `scanl` occurrences from second-last to first:

```
1 : 1 : 2 : take 0 (scanl (+) (2 + 1) (scanl (+) (1 + 1) (scanl (+) 1 (1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs))))
=
1 : 1 : 2 : take 0 (scanl (+) (2 + 1) (scanl (+) (1 + 1) (1 : scanl (+) (1 + 1) (scanl (+) 1 fibs))))
=
1 : 1 : 2 : take 0 (scanl (+) (2 + 1) (2 : scanl (+) (2 + 1) (scanl (+) (1 + 1) (scanl (+) 1 fibs))))
=
1 : 1 : 2 : take 0 (3 : scanl (+) (3 + 2) (scanl (+) (2 + 1) (scanl (+) (1 + 1) (scanl (+) 1 fibs))))
=
1 : 1 : 2 : take 0 (3 : scanl (+) 5 (scanl (+) 3 (scanl (+) 2 (scanl (+) 1 fibs))))
```

and you can see that `5`, not `4`, is slowly making its way into the calculation.

Comment: I can't tell you how much appreciate your through and detailed answer. Thank you so much. I understood everything you've just explained.